# В WPF элементы сьезжают вниз при компиляции

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

В WPF проекте у окна элементы "сьезжают" вниз при компиляции. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Может ли такое происходить из за того, что у Grid'а меньше Height чем у Window?

У Window `Width="550" Height="200"`, а у Grid `Width="550" Height="185"`

```
<Window x:Class="TestDB.Forms.Column"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDB.Forms"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Column" Height="200" Width="550" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Background="#FF363636">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18"  Margin="10" Background="#FF848383"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <Button Content="Ready" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: В VS выставил кнопки как нужно мне]
[[image: Кнопки сьехали вниз]]

Comment: Не пишите интерфейс, ориентируясь на конструктор студии, ибо он ужасен! Запустите проект, и пишите XAML, у вас прям в реал тайме будут видны изменения. Также не давайте строгих ограничений размеров всем контролам, дайте им свободу, пусть сами подстраиваются под размеры окна и прочего, например не ` Height="140"`, а `Height="3*"`. А по поводу самой проблемы, не забывайте, что есть такие вещи, как масштабирование самой системы, и прочие другие приблуды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не используйте марджины для позиционирования, не используйте пиксельные размеры. Размер рабочей области окна в дизайнере и в рабочем приложении может отличаться, это нормально

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid FontSize="18" Margin="10" Background="#FF848383"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Height="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Back" Padding="20,5" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Ready" Padding="20,5" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Кстати, `Grid.Row` и `Grid.Column` если надо `0`, то можно не задавать.